# Conditional Parameter in Where Clause in SSRS

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008

I'm wondering if there might be a solution to an issue I am experiencing. I am building a report that displays promotional information of drives/events for a given area.

But my issue is we have two types of drives: fixed site and mobiles. Mobile drives take place at businesses/schools/places in the community while fixed sites are located in a physical building owned by the business.  And mobile drives have recruiters who manage the drives and accounts, while fixed site drives do not.

If I put a parameter on the SSRS report for recruiters, I do not get records back from fixed sites.  Presumably because my parameter in the dataset is:

```
Where (RecID in (@RecruiterID))
```

And since Fixed Sites are NULL in this particular field, I'm not getting anything back.  The way to identify if a drive/event is a mobile or fixed site is the OwnerType column which is 0 for mobiles or 1 for fixed sites.

How can or should I modify this to take in Fixed Site records into my report?

Comment: I added the following to my Where clause: WHERE
Case When Owner_Type='Mobile' Then (RecID In (@RecruiterID) Else (RecID IS NULL)end but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Would the report display different data based on the 'Type of Drive' (fixed or mobile)? Or would you need to display both types in the same report.

- If the former Create another Parameter that indicates what type of drive and only pull the data for that type
- If the latter you could do something like

  select * from table 
  where 
  (      (OwnerType = 0) and (RecID in (@RecruiterID))  ) or (      (OwnerType = 0) and (RecID is null)  )

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.  The report needs to pull both fixed sites and mobile drives.  So the 2nd option should be my best bet.